# After importing a module (func1.py) into the test.py file, getting nameError: name ‘pd’ is not defined

Tags: python

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/name/Documents/pythontemp/functemp/')
In the test.py file:
import pandas as pd
for file in os.listdir('/Users/name/Documents/pythontemp/functemp/'):
    if 'func' not in file:
        continue
    fileN=file.split('.')[0]
    print(fileN)

    Class=__import__(fileN)
    func=getattr(Class,fileN)

    para=func.__code__.co_varnames
    print(para)
    if 'n1' not in para:
        idx=func.__code__.co_argcount
    else:
        idx=para.index('n1')
    print(idx)
    paras=[eval(x) for x in para[:(idx)]]
    #print(paras)
    dict_=dict(zip(para[:idx],paras))
    #print(dict_)

    factor=func(**dict_)
    display(factor)
```

---

> The nameError is:
>
> ```
> func2
> ('a', 'b', 'c', 'result')
>
> 3
> ```

---

```
NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)

   <ipython-input-9-4b45b006dea5> in <module>
        22     #print(dict_)
        23
   ---> 24     factor=func(**dict_)
        25     display(factor)

   ~/Documents/pythontemp/functemp/func2.py in func2(a, b, c)
         1 def func2(a,b,c):
   ----> 2     a=pd.DataFrame(a)
         3     result=a+b-c
         4     return result

   NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

---

The func2.py file is:

```
def func2(a,b,c):
    a=pd.DataFrame(a)
    result=a+b-c
    return result
```

---

I have lots of py file like `func2.py`(eg.`func1.py`, `func3.py`...) in the same file folder.
In the `test.py`, I have `imported pd`, but `func2.py` not.

So how to solve it?

Comment: `import pandas as pd`

Comment: if you call `pd.DataFrame` in `func2.py` then you need to `import pandas as pd` in that file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have hundreds of the py files like func2.py. Is there other solutions that I do not need to write ‘import pandas as pd’ in each file? For example, how to write another file in the same file folder with func2.py to avoid write the ‘import’ in every file? Or how to modify in the test.py file? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The `NameError` in `func2.py` is because that file does not know what `pd` is because you have not imported it in that file. Note that you have correctly imported pandas in the `test.py` file. Add the following to the top each of the `func*.py` files that have pd:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have hundreds of the py files like func2.py. Is there other solutions that I do not need to write ‘import pandas as pd’ in each file? For example, how to write another file in the same file folder with func2.py to avoid write the ‘import’ in every file? Or how to modify in the test.py file? Thanks again for your time.